# What is this hole in the nose of the A330?

Tags: airbus-a330, nose

In [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25926/is-it-possible-to-reach-an-a340s-fuselage-from-the-ground) question, there is an image of a ladder leading to some hole in the bottom of the nose of an A330. What is that hole for?

[image]

[Source](http://www.flugzeugbilder.de/show.php?id=695499)

Comment: Booo!!! -1 for a green circle instead of a red circle!!! (just kiddin')

Comment: @FreeMan Was not me though. ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is the avionic compartment access door as described in the [Flight Crew Operating Manual](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi21JGinbHLAhXLkywKHRofDukQFghFMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smartcockpit.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fpath%3Ddocs%2F%26file%3DA330-Doors.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGKxE3TjwqtDoRrEkB4bK_1O_po9A&sig2=pfYXX8zavoCn8YlIM1U3fw)!

> An inward-opening, manually operated, hinged door gives access to the avionics compartment. This door is in the lower fuselage, forward of the nose landing gear bay. A ladder is stowed inside the compartment adjacent to this door, which may be either be operated from the interior or the exterior.
>   This compartment is also accessible from the cockpit, via a floor hatch located behind the Captains' seat. A fixed ladder in the avionics compartment for access from the cockpit.

Here is a drawing from the outside!

[image: [A330 Avionics Hatch]

And here a view from the cockpit flight deck for an A340!

[image: A340 Flight deck Layout]

Comment: Like a server room for the airplane. I swear they always make the IT guy work in the worst conditions. ;-)

Comment: @ToddWilcox what are you talking about? They even got their own ladder for extra speedy boarding!

Comment: Any picture of the inside ?

Comment: Your first picture also accidentally answered http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25896/what-is-this-door-above-the-cockpit-of-a-747

Answer (score 13):

That 'hole' gives access to the avionics comparment- forward zone. The comparment has a ground access ladder, which is seen in the image. The deployment of that ladder (which is similar in A330/A340) can be seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKrHO6a04Cw).